# Play and Seek Audio File in iOS

Tags: ios, audio

Is there an equivalent class in iOS to the Java Clip class which would allow me to set the position in WAV file in seconds and play the sound from that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html) class' [playAtTime:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/playAtTime%3a) method.